# What is the current flag load like on Meta.SE?

Tags: discussion, flags, meta

As there are no moderators specifically for Meta.SE, what is the flag load like at the moment?

The site has been operating for a while now, is there much work building up at all?

(I custom flagged something today, I'm wondering how long it will take to be actioned. I know it's still the weekend in SE land and I know I'm impatient, but when things are not correctly categorized then there is an imbalance in the universe).

Comment: There _are_ actually moderators - the SE staff are moderating Meta.SE

Comment: I can't imagine the volume is high, but my last mod-handled flag took a few days to get resolved.  Probably just not a priority for the SE staff (and fewer eyes than there were on MSO).

Comment: @slugster, there may be some remote workers for SE who could have different weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment?

I see three active flags. The Community Team do deal with the flag load no problem...

Sometimes if I am active on a post where a flag occurred I will handle it myself (if there is no conflict of interest), but the flag volume is not high.